# Send JSON and FormData (Angular to Spring)

Tags: angular, spring

**Angular**

```
register(usuario:any, id: File): Observable<any>{

 let formData = new FormData();
 
 formData.append("user", JSON.stringify({username:'Userr'}));
 formData.append("file", id);

 return this.http.post(AUTH_API + 'signup', formData);
```

**CODE**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjSXH.png)

**SPRING**

```
@PostMapping(value = "/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser( @RequestParam SignupRequest user,
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile archivo) {
         
    
        System.out.println(archivo.getSize());
        System.out.println(user.getUsername());
}
```

**ERROR**
2021-01-02 16:50:55.397  WARN 15076 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException:

**Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'SignupRequest';**

nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.AreMyNews.Request.SignupRequest': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]

Answer (score 0):

Use @ModelAttribute instead of @RequestParam for SignupRequest user.

```
PostMapping(value = "/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser( @ModelAttribute SignupRequest user,
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile archivo) {
         
    
        System.out.println(archivo.getSize());
        System.out.println(user.getUsername());
}
```

Comment: It doesnt work, username is null with modelAttribute

Comment: try @ModelAttribute("user") SignupRequest user

Comment: also, be aware that , you have mentioned JSON.stringfy({username:'Userr'}). So, in your SignupRequest class, the field name should be username